# Adding custom object to firebase yields extraneous data member called "true"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'll attach my code below, but the gist is this: I am writing a custom class into my firebase console, and everything is working great, but I keep getting an extra variable saved into the database, and weirder still is the fact that it is entitled "true" and set to "false". I have no idea how or why this is happening. Any ideas?

**Picture**

[image: Database]

**Question.java**

```
public class Question {
    String details,title;
    Boolean isTrue;
    String source;
    double explanation;

    Question(String t, String q, Boolean d, String s, double r) {
        details = q;
        title = t;
        isTrue = d;
        source = s;
        explanation = r;
    }
    Question() {
        details = "Blank";
        title = "Blank";
        isTrue = true;
        source = "http://google.com";
        explanation = 0.0;
    }
    Question(String rawData) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rawData.length(); i++)
        {
            if (rawData.charAt(i) == 'ß')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count != 5)
        {
            details = "Blank";
            title = "Blank";
            isTrue = true;
            source = "http://google.com";
            explanation = 0.0;
        } else {
            String[] values = rawData.split("ß");
            title = values[0];
            details = values[1];
            isTrue = false;
            if (values[2].equals("T"))
                isTrue = true;
            source = values[3];
            explanation = Double.parseDouble(values[4]);
        }
    }

    String getDetails() { return details; }
    String getTitle() { return title; }
    Boolean isTrue() { return isTrue; }
    String getSource() { return source; }
    double getExplanation() { return explanation; }

    public void setDetails(String q) { details = q; }
    public void setTitle(String t) { title = t; }
    public void setTrue(Boolean i) { isTrue = i; }
    public void setSource(String s) { source = s; }
    public void setExplanation(Double r) { explanation = r; }

    public String toString() {
        String s = title + "ß" + details + "ß";
        if (isTrue)
            s += "T";
        else
            s += "F";
        s += "ß";
        s += source + "ß" + Double.toString(explanation);
        return s;
    }
}
```

**Writing to the database**

```
    title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_title);
    details = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_details);
    source = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_source);
    truth = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_truth);
    explanation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_explanation);
    if (explanation.getText().equals(""))
        explanation.setText("0.0");

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Question questionToAdd = new Question(title.getText().toString(),details.getText().toString(),truth.isPressed(),source.getText().toString(),Double.parseDouble(explanation.getText().toString()));
            Toast.makeText(AddQuestion.this,mDatabase.child("Quotes").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mDatabase.child("Quotes").push().setValue(questionToAdd).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddQuestion.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (RuntimeException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a minimal test class: `public static class WithBoolean {
        Boolean isTrue;
        public Boolean isTrue() { return isTrue; }
        public void setTrue(Boolean value) { isTrue = value; }
    }`. Can you see if you can reduce the class to a [smaller version that still reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I actually think I'm going to move on now that it's fixed. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using simple 'toHashMap' function, for example:

```
public HashMap toHashMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("details", details);    
    map.put("title", title);    
    map.put("isTrue", isTrue);    
    map.put("source", source);    
    map.put("explanation", explanation);
   return map;
}
```

And then:

```
.... 
mDatabase.child("Quotes").push().setValue(questionToAdd.toHashMap())....
```

Comment: That did it! Still confused why it happened in the first place, but whatever. I'm glad it's solved!